# Plotly map: inverse colorscale tick values

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

In Plotly maps (Python), how can I inverse the tick labels on the colorscale so that the smallest value is at the top and the largest at the bottom? For example, -100 at the top and 100 at the bottom?

Note: I do not want to change the colors, just the associated tick values.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the [ticktext](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#scattergeo-marker-colorbar-ticktext) input

In your colorbar definition, include `tickmode="array"` along with `ticktext=` and `tickvals=`
Something like this:

`colorbar=dict(tickmode="array",ticktext=[100,-100],tickvals=[-100,100])`

Comment: In order to flip the colorbar itself, the color value can be plotted as negative, then this answer applied.