# Reverse colorbar in Plotly for Python

Tags: python, plotly, colorbar

I create a heatmap with a colorbar in Plotly:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import plot
my_heatmap = go.Heatmap(x=x, y=y, z=z, colorscale='Jet')
plot(my_heatmap)
```

I choose the colorscale to be Jet so it goes from blue (small values of z) to red (large values of z).

Now it turns out that in my application I actually want small values of z to correspond to the red color. Thus, I do:

```
go.Heatmap(x=x, y=y, z=z, colorscale='Jet', reversescale=True)
```

This solves the problem on the heatmap itself: Small values are now red, large values are blue.

**Problem** But, the colorbar itself also flipped now displaying the color corresponding to low z on top! I feel like I missed something in the documentation... Is there a way I can flip the physical colorbar itself upsidedown?

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36231323/plotly-map-inverse-colorscale-tick-values) can help. I am tried to do with `ticktext` and `tickvalues`, but did not succeeded now